# Count rows in Oracle table

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I need to count rows in Oracle table by type:

```
CREATE TABLE EVENTS(
  EVENTID INTEGER NOT NULL,
  SOURCE VARCHAR2(50 ),
  TYPE VARCHAR2(50 ),
  EVENT_DATE DATE,
  DESCRIPTION VARCHAR2(100 )
)
/
```

I need 4 types of events - Critical, Info, Warning and  Error

How I can do this with one SQL query?

The final result should be one row result like this:

```
All | Critical | Info | Warning | Error
-------------------------------------------
23  |   2      |  13  |    2    |   3
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*) "All",
    COUNT(CASE WHEN TYPE = 'Critical' THEN 1 END) "Critical",
    COUNT(CASE WHEN TYPE = 'Info' THEN 1 END) "Info",
    COUNT(CASE WHEN TYPE = 'Warning' THEN 1 END) "Warning",
    COUNT(CASE WHEN TYPE = 'Error' THEN 1 END) "Error"
FROM
    EVENTS;
```

Answer (score 1):

or using pivot

```
SELECT * FROM
(
  SELECT type, count(*) over() "All"
  FROM events
)
PIVOT
(

  COUNT(type)
  FOR type IN ('Critical', 'Info', 'Warning', 'Error')
)
```

Comment: I get ORA-00937: not a single-group group function
00937. 00000 -  "not a single-group group function"

Comment: this only works for 11g and up, sorry should have mentioned that

Comment: I use 11g XE. Well looks like I can't use it

Comment: no my bad sorry I left something out I will update the answer.

Comment: While this answer is probably correct and useful, it is preferred if you [include some explanation along with it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/159034) to explain how it helps to solve the problem. This becomes especially useful in the future, if there is a change (possibly unrelated) that causes it to stop working and readers need to understand how it once worked.